# Getting error MyODBC Field 'img_valid' doesn't have a default value AFTER moving server

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, odbc

i am moving sites running on iis, they are currently running on a shared server and I am moving them to a VPS. from classic ASP files i am getting the error "[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.34]Field 'field_name' doesn't have a default value".

It is easy to fix from the database by allowing the field to be null for instance, however, I have over 200 sites to move and I am going to spend a life time looking for those errors on each site and fixing them.
I have looked online to see if there is a configuration / setting that needs to be changed on the ODBC connection or MySQL so I would not have to go and modify every database and the site would work normally on the new server but can't seem to find anything. Would anyone know?

The new server is a windows server 2008 R2 running IIS 7

Comment: I suppose you could try installing older versions of the MyODBC driver and see if they're a bit less uncompromising, but I have no idea if it will make any difference.  I'm guessing the server move means you're now on a later version of MySQL, this often throws up these sort of problems.  It can be even worse if you're trying to connect from a .net site

Comment: Thank you, I did fear there would be no solution with the current ODBC version, seems like I might have to bite the bullet and update the databases.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14306

- open `my.ini` in folder D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0 , or whatever folder
- Change `sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"` to `sql-mode=""`
- restart mysql service

It appears the important part is turning off `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`. Per [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables):

> If a value could not be inserted as given into a transactional table, abort the statement. For a nontransactional table, abort the statement if the value occurs in a single-row statement or the first row of a multiple-row statement.